# Отделяется ли запятой "согласно чему-то"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, пунктуация

Имеем такое предложение: "Согласно правил форума(,) мы не выполняем домашние задания, а просим предложить свой вариант ответа, который потом исправим в случае необходимости". И вот, вопрос совершенно банальный и совершенно не новый, но меня заклинило: нужна ли запятая после "согласно правил форума"? И еще: как правильнее сказать "согласно правил" или "согласно правилам"? Я сперва написал "согласно правилам", а потом засомневался и исправил на "согласно правил".
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

"Согласно правилам форума, мы не выполняем домашние задания, а просим предложить свой вариант ответа, который потом исправим в случае необходимости".

1) Обособление

Уже отвечено Грамотой в [Приложении "Пунктуация при оборотах с непервообразными предлогами"](http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach1/):

> Такие конструкции могут обособляться, однако пунктуационная трудность состоит в том, что их обособление не всегда уместно, а иногда даже ошибочно.
>
> Оборот обособляется, если требуется обозначить его границы (чтобы предложение не выглядело двусмысленным):
>
> *Во избежание неверного понимания фразы директором, были внесены изменения в документ. – Во избежание неверного понимания фразы, директором были внесены изменения в документ.*
>
> Оборот не обособляется, если он входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу. (Как правило, в таких случаях оборот нельзя изъять из состава предложения, не исказив при этом смысл фразы.) Например:
>
> *...Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат с согласия отца украл у него лошадь... М. Лермонтов, Герой нашего времени. (смысл у Лермонтова: Казбич вообразил, будто отец Азамата дал согласие на кражу.) Ср. изменение смысла при обособлении оборота: ...Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат, с согласия отца, украл у него лошадь... (=Казбич вообразил, будто Азамат украл лошадь.)*
>
> В остальных случаях можно говорить о факультативности обособления оборота (в зависимости от степени его распространенности, близости к основной части предложения, порядка слов в предложении, авторского замысла и других факторов). При этом можно выделить ряд факторов, влияющих на постановку знаков препинания.

Answer (score 1):

2) Падеж

Грамота уже отвечала на этот вопрос ([Вопрос №257193](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_392032)):

> Нормативна только форма ***дательного*** падежа после предлога *согласно*.

То есть, "согласно правилам форума".

Answer (score 0):

У вас в вопросе написано "согласно чему-то" – совершенно правильно. Почему же "согласно правил"?

По поводу обособления почитайте здесь:

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm

§94. Обособленные обстоятельства

Примечание к п.4.